# MySQL InnoDB data serialization

Tags: mysql, innodb

Take the following situation: 
On a system with an innodb_page_size of 16KB. 
I write two rows with each the fixed length of 1KB per row.

Question: 
Will InnoDB write both rows on one page, filling the one page with 2KB of data, or will InnoDB write each row to it's own page, filling two pages with 1KB each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB will fill one Page with 2kB of your Data + Headers, fill trailer etc..

Also InnoDB will only fill 15/16 of a page to let space for updates and future inserts

If you really want to get into this i recommend reading:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-example.html

and

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html